# User stats required for an offline iOS web app

Tags: ios, web, offline

I'm creating an iPad bespoke web app for a sales team which, on occasions, will need to work offline. So far, so good.

The client wants to be able to grabs stats of when the app is used by the sales team? Am I able to write to a file locally, then upload this file or email it at a given time?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer is YES!

You can write and read any kinds of file to your app document. Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078647/how-to-read-write-file-with-ios-in-simulator-as-well-as-on-device). After grabbing your file info, you can send it by email or dropbox or......