# How to get file from destination path

Tags: objective-c, iphone, nsfilemanager

I dont know about how to open `NSFileManager`.
How to open `NSFileManager` in iPhone and upload document from `NSFileManager` please suggest any easy way.

How can open it and upload the document and also get the path for saved file.

Where I can find file physically.(Any location).

**::EDIT::**

I started coding in that year. so, i don't know about basic of `NSFileManager`.

Comment: Check this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078647/how-to-read-write-file-with-ios-in-simulator-as-well-as-on-device/11078682

Comment: @Mukesh can this work like dialogue box and can i select document from them?

Comment: This may be an A-B question, could you please describe the details of your background?

Answer (score 0):

**Show contents:**

```
 NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@", [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error]);
```

**Get all files**

```
//get an instance of the File Manager
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

   //we'll list file in the temporary directory

NSString * strPath = NSTemporaryDirectory();

//we'll need NSURL for the File Manager
NSURL *tempDirURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:strPath];


  //An array of NSURL object representing the path to the file
    //using the flag NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles to skip hidden files

NSArray *directoryList = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:tempDirURL 
                      includingPropertiesForKeys:nil 
              options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles error:nil];
```

Reference:http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/file-saving-and-loading/using-the-document-directory-to-store-files

http://nshipster.com/nsfilemanager/

Comment: What I am not getting you

Answer (score 0):

An iPhone's documents directory is used for saving data. We can save some personal data like as file, image, video etc. The document's directory's data will remain in the iPhone's memory until the application is forcibly terminated.

Let's see an example of how to store some images & retrieve those images later in an iPhone.

```
// For saving the images in the Document's Directory

-(void)saveImagesInIPhone:(NSData*)imageData withName:(NSString*)imageName

{

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  

 //Get the docs directory

NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 

NSString *folderPath = [documentsDirectoryPath  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"IconImages"];  // subDirectory

 if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:folderPath])

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:folderPath  withIntermediateDirectories:NOattributes:nil error:nil];



//Add the FileName to FilePath

NSString *filePath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[iconName   stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@",@".png"]];

//Write the file to documents directory

[imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; 

}
```

**Result**:- /var/mobile/Applications/20F869FD-5C61-4900-8CFE-830907731EC9/Documents/Designer0.png

---

```
  ///To retrieve the images from the document Directory

 -(UIImage*)retrieveImageFromPhone:(NSString*)fileNamewhichtoretrieve

{

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  

 //Get the docs directory

NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 


NSString *folderPath = [documentsPath   stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"IconImages"];  // subDirectory


NSString *filePath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:

                      [fileNamewhichtoretrieve stringByAppendingFormat:

                        @"%@",@".png"]];


if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])

    return [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

else 

    return nil;

}
```

**result** :- /var/mobile/Applications/20F869FD-5C61-4900-8CFE-830907731EC9/Documents/Designer0.png

Comment: i have all path and related query but not open like android file manager where we take photos,docs,etc... from where it stored.

Comment: No you cant do this unlike filemanager app in android. You can programmatically perform operations only.

Comment: Yes sure bro why not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166820/discussion-between-realmoffire-and-mr-javed-multani).

Answer (score 0):

You can get Directory Path like this..

```
-(NSString *)getDBPath
{
    //Searching a standard documents using NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"I am in --> getDBPath==%@",paths);

    return [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"abcd_DB.sqlite"];
}
```

**If you are using iOS Devices- 
You can get Your DB directly by using https://macroplant.com/iexplorer Application.

**If you are using Simulator.

1. Get the Path directory
2. In terminal : open directory Path(Past your Directory Path).
3. Copy your DB and brows it with Firefox or sqlite browser.